# strip all vs debug symbols

Tags: linux, debugging, executable

I am looking at the 'strip' command in Linux.  I see an option for strip all symbols and sections (-S), and strip all symbols and relocation information (-s).

What is the difference?  I just want to protected my code from being hacked/reverse engineered.  It seems like removing relocation information may impede normal use of the executable, so I'm not sure if that option is risky?

Answer (score 1):

-S removes debug symbols. -s is what you want to mildly annoy someone doing reverse engineering.  It does not prevent running the code.

```
gcc -o hello -g hello.c
nm hello |wc
     60     177    2462
strip -S hello 
nm hello |wc
     60     177    2462
strip -s hello 
nm hello |wc
hello: no symbols
      0       0       0
./hello
Hello, World!
```

Comment: What is the impact of removing relocation information (part of -s) ?  Is relocation information necessary for loading the executable, or managing memory?  Would --strip-debug and --strip-unneeded be the safest way to strip all debug info?

Comment: You need relocations for an object file or library so that you can load it to different addresses.  For an executable that is already linked, you don't need relocations.

Comment: My executable uses dynamic linking, so I guess "-s" is not suitable.  Is --strip-debug combined with --strip-unneeded the closest equivalent to "-s" while retaining relocation information?

Comment: Eh?  Are you going to relink the executable to a different address, or are you just using dlopen, dlsym on libraries which do have relocation info?

Comment: I'm afraid that I lack the technical depth to answer your questions.  I just remember reading that on loading the OS will locate/relocate pieces of code.